# How can I get a specific date with MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, schedule

How can I get a specific date with MomentJS?

For example: I would like start generating days from March 1 2020.

Thanks!

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: By hosting it on a repo for instance?

Comment: No, you can [edit] the post and in the editor you can add a working snippet of what you tried and then explain the issues you're having with the code. Or you can accept the answer below if this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their docs you can parse a text date into a moment object:

`var myDate = moment("2020-03-01");`

From: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

After that you can add time (days) to the object:

`myDate.add(1, 'days');`

From: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: Thanks! It's precisely what I was looking for!